# Why isn't Scalar::Util::Numeric installing correctly?

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

I got this output when running `sudo cpan Scalar::Util::Numeric`

```
jmm@freekbox:~/bfwsandbox/sa/angel/astroportal/dtu8e/resources$ sudo cpan Scalar::Util::Numeric
[sudo] password for jmm:
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /home/jmm/.cpan/Metadata
  Database was generated on Tue, 09 Sep 2008 16:02:51 GMT
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Going to read /home/jmm/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Going to read /home/jmm/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
  Database was generated on Tue, 16 Sep 2008 16:02:50 GMT

  There's a new CPAN.pm version (v1.9205) available!
  [Current version is v1.7602]
  You might want to try
    install Bundle::CPAN
    reload cpan
  without quitting the current session. It should be a seamless upgrade
  while we are running...

Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Going to read /home/jmm/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Going to write /home/jmm/.cpan/Metadata
Running install for module Scalar::Util::Numeric
Running make for C/CH/CHOCOLATE/Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::MD5 loaded ok
Checksum for /home/jmm/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CH/CHOCOLATE/Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/jmm/.cpan/build for sizes
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/Changes
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/lib/
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/lib/Scalar/
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/lib/Scalar/Util/
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/lib/Scalar/Util/Numeric.pm
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/Makefile.PL
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/MANIFEST
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/META.yml
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/Numeric.xs
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/ppport.h
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/README
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/t/
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/t/pod.t
Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02/t/Scalar-Util-Numeric.t
Removing previously used /home/jmm/.cpan/build/Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02

  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CH/CHOCOLATE/Scalar-Util-Numeric-0.02.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Scalar::Util::Numeric
cp lib/Scalar/Util/Numeric.pm blib/lib/Scalar/Util/Numeric.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Scalar/Util/Numeric.pm (blib/lib/auto/Scalar/Util/Numeric)
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl/5.8/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl/5.8/ExtUtils/typemap  Numeric.xs > Numeric.xsc && mv Numeric.xsc Numeric.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTHREADS_HAVE_PIDS -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3   -DVERSION=\"0.02\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.02\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE"   Numeric.c
In file included from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:420:24: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:451:19: error: ctype.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:463:23: error: locale.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:480:20: error: setjmp.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:486:26: error: sys/param.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:491:23: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:496:23: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:776:23: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:925:27: error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:929:26: error: arpa/inet.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:939:25: error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:961:21: error: time.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:968:25: error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:975:27: error: sys/times.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:982:19: error: errno.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:997:25: error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:1024:21: error: netdb.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:1127:24: error: sys/ioctl.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:1156:23: error: dirent.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.3/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.3/include/limits.h:11,
                 from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:1510,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.3/include/limits.h:122:61: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2120,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/handy.h:136:25: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2284,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/unixish.h:106:21: error: signal.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2421:33: error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2423: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘perl_os_thread’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2424: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘perl_mutex’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2425: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘perl_cond’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2426: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘perl_key’
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/iperlsys.h:51,
                 from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2733,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlio.h:65:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/iperlsys.h:51,
                 from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2733,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlio.h:259: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlio.h:262: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlio.h:265: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlio.h:268: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘FILE’
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2747,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/sv.h:389: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘DIR’
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/op.h:497,
                 from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2754,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:72:20: error: pwd.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:75:20: error: grp.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:85:26: error: crypt.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:90:27: error: shadow.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/op.h:497,
                 from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2754,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:612: error: field ‘_crypt_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:620: error: field ‘_drand48_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:624: error: field ‘_grent_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:635: error: field ‘_hostent_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:654: error: field ‘_netent_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:669: error: field ‘_protoent_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:684: error: field ‘_pwent_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:695: error: field ‘_servent_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:710: error: field ‘_spent_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:721: error: field ‘_gmtime_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:724: error: field ‘_localtime_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:771: error: field ‘_random_struct’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/reentr.h:772: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘int32_t’
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2756,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/av.h:13: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘ssize_t’
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2759,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/scope.h:232: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘sigjmp_buf’
In file included from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2931: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘getuid’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2932: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘geteuid’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2933: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘getgid’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:2934: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘getegid’
In file included from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:3238:22: error: math.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:3881,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/thrdvar.h:85: error: field ‘Tstatbuf’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/thrdvar.h:86: error: field ‘Tstatcache’ has incomplete type
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/thrdvar.h:91: error: field ‘Ttimesbuf’ has incomplete type
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:3883,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/intrpvar.h:66: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘time_t’
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:3950,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:128: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘mode_t’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:128: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uid_t’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:297: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘off64_t’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:299: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_do_sysseek’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:300: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_do_tell’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:411: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘gid_t’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:411: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uid_t’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:736: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_my_fork’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:1020: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘pid_t’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:1300: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘pid_t’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:1456: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:2001: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_PerlIO_read’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:2002: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_PerlIO_write’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:2003: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_PerlIO_unread’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:2004: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Perl_PerlIO_tell’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/proto.h:2005: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘off64_t’
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:3988,
                 from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlvars.h:31: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘PL_thr_key’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlvars.h:48: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘PL_op_mutex’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlvars.h:52: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘PL_dollarzero_mutex’
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:4485:24: error: sys/ipc.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:4486:24: error: sys/sem.h: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:4611:24: error: sys/file.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlapi.h:38,
                 from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/XSUB.h:349,
                 from Numeric.xs:3:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/intrpvar.h:66: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/intrpvar.h:237: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/intrpvar.h:238: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/intrpvar.h:239: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/intrpvar.h:240: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlapi.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/XSUB.h:349,
                 from Numeric.xs:3:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlvars.h:31: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlvars.h:48: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perlvars.h:52: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from Numeric.xs:4:
ppport.h:3042:1: warning: "PERL_UNUSED_DECL" redefined
In file included from Numeric.xs:2:
/usr/lib/perl/5.8/CORE/perl.h:163:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
Numeric.c: In function ‘XS_Scalar__Util__Numeric_is_num’:
Numeric.c:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:22: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:24: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:16: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:17: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:36: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:36: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c: In function ‘XS_Scalar__Util__Numeric_uvmax’:
Numeric.c:43: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:43: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:43: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:45: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:26: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:26: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:26: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:26: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.xs:26: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:51: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:51: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c: In function ‘boot_Scalar__Util__Numeric’:
Numeric.c:60: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:60: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:60: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:63: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:65: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:65: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:66: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:66: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:67: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:67: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:67: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
Numeric.c:67: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
make: *** [Numeric.o] Error 1
  /usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
jmm@freekbox:~/bfwsandbox/sa/angel/astroportal/dtu8e/resources$
```

Comment: “it looks like the line breaks aren't showing up in the preview window.” Yes, the formatting instructions at the left say you should insert 4 spaces or a tab in front of each line to make it a code block. If you paste into an editor for indenting first, this is very easy to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing your C library development headers. You should install a package that has them. These are necessary to install this module because it has to compile some non-perl C code and needs to know more about your system.

I can't tell what kind of operating system you're on, but it looks like linux. If it's debian, you should be able to use apt-get to install the 'libc6-dev' package. That will contain the headers you need to compile this module. On other types of linux there will be a similarly named package.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu, and "sudo apt-get install libc6-dev" did the trick. Thx much

Comment: on Debian or Ubuntu, "sudo apt-get install build-essential" will install this along with a few other useful -dev packages, compilers, etc

Comment: upgrade Perl while your at it ;) "Perl 5.8 was first released on July 18, 2002"

Answer (score 4):

It can't find basic system headers. Either your include path is seriously messed up, or the headers are not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Awfully hard to read without line breaks, but it looks like you are missing `sys/types.h` on your system. Do you have a full build environment installed (gcc, make, etc.)? What OS and distribution are you using?

In the future, you should bockquote output like this (select the text and click the quote button).